# What is the best way to make some kind of a row builder with multiple lines and pass JSON data into it. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

[image]

What is the best way in Flutter to achieve this kind of a layout where every cell has custom width and where I can pass JSON data into it? I tried using ListView and GridView, but none of them work.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Wrap`

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = [
      {'name': 'UK'},
      {'name': 'Banker'},
      {'name': '29'},
      {'name': 'Atheist'},
      {'name': 'Graduated'},
      {'name': '175 cm'},
      {'name': 'tx'}
    ];
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
                runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
                children: data
                    .map((e) => Chip(
                          avatar: Icon(
                            Icons.account_balance,
                            size: 18,
                          ),
                          label: Text(e['name']),
                        ))
                    .toList())));
  }
```